# Update UIKeyboardAppearance while keyboard is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, keyboard, uikit

Cocoa Touch allows to change the keyboard appearance by setting the keyboardAppearance property of the UITextInputTraits protocol, which is implemented in the UITextField and UITextView classes.

It seems that updating the keyboardAppearance property while the keyboard is already on the screen do not update the keyboard appearance.

As a workaround I was thinking to dismiss the keyboard and reopen it. Is there a better way to solve the issue?

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen the keyboard type switch styles while on screen. Even if you could, I wouldn't be surprised if that violates Apple's user interface guidelines during review. What specifically are you trying to do, maybe we can pitch alternate ideas?

Comment: This is part of an automatic theme change (light / dark or day / night) functionality similar to what implemented in Tweetbot and Tick. The former simply stick with the dark keyboard for both themes, while the latter simply dismiss the keyboard when the theme is automatically changed.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I don't have a better answer, then. Maybe set the theme based on time before the keyboard is open? At least then the next time the keyboard is naturally reopened, it'll match.

Answer (score 3):

It's an annoying limitation, I have the same requirement.

The only option I could find was to call:

```
self.textView.resignFirstResponder()
self.textView.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark
self.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

It worked without refreshing but because I'm wired up to the UIKeyboardWillShow/HideNotifications which change contentInsets etc, there was a visible reshuffle of the content underneath the keyboard.